# Ajax process from point of initiating a request to user seeing result?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, process

I'm looking for a straight forward list(with any notable information to match the point) of the separate processes involved from initiating the request object to the user seeing the end result in AJAX?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'll give it a shot.

- Initiate a request to the server from JavaScript.  At some level this is XmlHttpRequest but you are better off using a library such as jQuery to help.
- Get a response back from the server.  Usually the response is JSON or HTML.  Using XML is not recommended because parsing XML in JavaScript is not fun.
- Update the HTML DOM to show the results from the server.  This is very application-specific.  But again using jQuery or some other library makes this easier.

Comment: You don't need to parse the XML in JavaScript.  That's what `responseXML` is for.